# Is it possible to identify an object based on an index?

Tags: java, oop, object

So lets say i have a class Bus, and i have two instances of bus.

`Bus bus1 = new Bus();
Bus bus2 = new Bus();`

Now if i prompt a user to inter an index, lets say he enters 2. How can i verify if bus2 exists?

Comment: You are going to need a way to find the indicated bus, which itself solves the existence issue.  Crudely, you can write 'if user entered 1 use bus1 else if 2 then use bus2 else it does not exist'.  But using a different named variable for each bus is not the right way.  You need to store the buses in a collection where they can be retrieved by id - say an array (if ids are dense) or a set.

Answer (score 0):

I would say that a Bus should be identified by an ID not just because it is the second one to be created.
So assuming you add a property

```
private int ID
```

to the Bus class and override, in Bus class,

```
  @Override
  public int hashCode() {
    final int prime = 31;
    int result = 1;
    result = prime * result + ID;
    return result;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (this == obj)
      return true;
    if (obj == null)
      return false;
    if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
      return false;
    Bus other = (Bus) obj;
    if (ID != other.ID)
      return false;
    return true;
  }
```

you can discriminate between two Bus contained in a list

```
listOfBuses.contains(new Bus(userInput))
```

Comment: For a new Bus to be found in the listOfBuses, the ids much be equal. Therefore, you've got two Bus objects with the same id, and ids are no longer unique.  Sure, you can distinguish 'real buses' and 'fake lookup temporary buses' (as here) but that does not seem good.

Answer (score 0):

First we automatically number our buses.

```
class Bus {
    private static int lastId = 0;
    int id;

    Bus() {
       id = ++lastId; // assign unique bus id
    }

    int getId() {
        return id;
    }
}
```

Somewhere we track our buses as they are created.  Since we want to track by the integer id number, a map from id to bus is useful.  (We could also use an array as the bus numbers are allocated densely, but a map has some advantages if buses are destroyed as well as created, since bus numbers are no longer necessarily dense).

```
Map<Integer, Bus> busMap = new HashMap<>();

bus = new Bus(); // 1
busMap.put(bus.getId(), bus);

bus = new Bus(); // 2
busMap.put(bus.getId(), bus);
```

Now to retrieve/validate a bus (assume user input in `int b`):

```
   bus = busMap.get(b);
   if (bus == null) 
      … then b is not a valid bus id …

   … otherwise we have the bus we wanted …
```